# Ext.Net:after loading combobox,set the selected item value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ext.net

I have a combobox,After I load combobox from a table,I get the selected item value from another table ,and bind it inside the combobox,
however my combobox loaded but didnt show me selected item inside it.
here is the my code.

```
<ext:ComboBox runat="server" ID="cmbPerson" EmptyText="select person"  AllowBlank="false" 
      Editable="false" Icon="User" Flex="1" ValueField="Id" DisplayField="Name" FieldLabel="">
        <Store>
        <ext:Store ID="strcmbPerson" runat="server">
         <Model>
         <ext:Model ID="Model1" runat="server">
         <Fields>
         <ext:ModelField Name="Id" />
         <ext:ModelField Name="Name" />
         </Fields>
    </ext:Model>
    </Model>
    </ext:Store>
         </Store>
    </ext:ComboBox>





     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   

//I populated combobox from databese,
           strcmbPerson.DataSource = person_bll.Get();
           strcmbPerson.DataBind();    

//later I wanna set selected item value to the "person_obj.PersonId"
                cmbPerson.SelectedItem.Value = Convert.ToString(person_obj.PersonId);                                                        

                }
```

Comment: I fixed thr problem setting combobox value type to string.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim ExtItem As New Ext.Net.ListItem  
ExtItem.Value = dst.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2)
ExtItem.Mode = ParameterMode.Raw
MultiCombo1.SelectedItems.Add(ExtItem)
```

Comment: I believe it would be good to add a little text to explain the above.